# Count Same Value Laravel Collection

Tags: laravel, collections, distinct

I want to count same value on laravel collection here is my array :

```
[
 'January' => [
  [
   'status' => 'active',
  ], [
   'status' => 'active',
  ], [
   'status' => 'disable',
  ], [
   'status' => 'active',
  ], 

  'February' => [
   'status' => 'active',
  ], [
   'status' => 'active',
  ], [
   'status' => 'disable',
  ], [
   'status' => 'disable',
  ], 
 ]
```

I want to count same value to be like this:

```
[
 'January' => [
  'active' => 3
  'disable' => 1,
 ], 

 'February' => [
  'active' => 2,
  'disable' => 2,
 ]
```

How to do this use laravel collection ?

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Comment: i loop it again and make it as collection and group it again but not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Collection's `map` and `countBy` to do this:

```
collect($array)->map(fn ($i) => collect($i)->countBy('status'));
```